# Bytes Received always returning 0

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I'm trying to use the C# PerformanceCounter class to return system metrics.

```
// Initialisation
// Threads (total threads for all processes)
PerformanceCounter performThreads = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter();
((ISupportInitialize)(performThreads)).BeginInit();
performThreads.CategoryName = "System";
performThreads.CounterName = "Threads";
((ISupportInitialize)(performThreads)).EndInit();

// Bytes received (cumulative total bytes received over all open socket connections)
private PerformanceCounter m_pcSys_BytesSent;
PerformanceCounter performBytesR = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter();
((ISupportInitialize)(performBytesR)).BeginInit();
performBytesR.CategoryName = ".NET CLR Networking";
performBytesR.CounterName = "Bytes Received";
performBytesR.InstanceName = "_global_";
((ISupportInitialize)(performBytesR)).EndInit();

// Later on ... periodically poll performance counters
long lThreads = performThreads.RawValue;    // Works!
long lBytesR = performBytesR.RawValue;      // Always returns 0 :o(
```

The last line above works in the sense that it does not throw an exception but always returns 0.

I have tried both `NextSample` and `NextValue` with the same result. If I change `InstanceName` to the process name I again get the same result. If `InstanceName` is set to anything else the exception `Instance 'XYZ' does not exist in the specified Category.` is thrown when I call `RawValue`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a sniffer like fiddler or wireshark to verify that the data is being sent/received over the network.

Comment: @AlainD: If you're into collecting system-level metrics, see if [Statsify](https://bitbucket.org/aeroclub-it/statsify) fits your needs.

Comment: @jdweng: Data is certainly being sent/received because I am connected to various servers using Windows sockets. I can count up the bytes being sent and received manually (and they are non-zero). The problem turns out to be that .NET networking performance counters must be specifically enabled as per Anton's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Networking Performance Counters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70xadeyt(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Networking performance counters need to be enabled in the configuration file to be used.
>
> If networking counters are enabled, this will create and update both per-AppDomain and global performance counters. If disabled, the application will not provide any networking performance counter data.

Comment: That worked! But not without a bit of hassle. If the required `<performanceCounters enabled="true" />` entry is placed at the top of the app.config file, then networking stops altogether for my application (can no longer connect over sockets). I had a SQLEXPRESS connection string in app.config. By putting the `<performanceCounters enabled="true" />` section at the bottom of app.config, the process started returning bytes received and sent! Thanks.